# Algorithm to find the best combination of a list if given sets

Tags: algorithm, set, subset

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the best combination (the highest weight) of a list of sets. For example, let's say we have items 'A', 'B' and 'C' and we got 4 A's, 2 B's and 3 C's. Some possible combinations could be:

```
{A,B,C},{A,B,C},{A,C},{A}
{A,B},{A,B,C},{A,C},{A,C}
```

Then the weights are based on the number of items per set, for example:

1 item: 5

2 items: 15

3 items: 20

So in this case the first combination would have a weight of 20+20+15+5=60 and the second one would be 15+20+15+15=65. A greedy algorithm wouldn't work in this case because there are cases where looking for the highest number of items does not return the best combination.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say _"best combination"_ do you mean the heaviest or lightest?

Comment: [Integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) could do the trick, if it's fine for you.

Comment: Sounds like a dynamic programming problem. BTW: 20+20+15+5=60. And if you are looking for the lowest total, then sets with 1 item will always be the answer (for the given weights).

Comment: goal is to have more pairs of 2 right? 6 items in pairs of 2 would have more weight(+5) than 6 items in pairs of 3..

Comment: @molamk the idea is to have the heaviest

Comment: @ACD with these case, seems so, but the idea is to find it with dynamic weights

Comment: @user3386109 oh yep, it's 60, i was sleepy when I wrote it. And the idea is to find the heaviest weight possible

Comment: Is it allowed to have combination `AAAABBCCC`? Are there rules for creating combinations?

Comment: @Yola No, they must be sets, so they cannot be repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using recursion.

These variables define the problem (static variables):

```
private static boolean[] BEST_SOLUTION_SO_FAR = null;
private static int BEST_WEIGHT_SO_FAR = 0;

private static String[][] POSSIBLE_SETS =  {{"A","B","C"},{"A","B","C"},{"A","C"},{"A"},{"A","B"},{"A","B","C"},{"A","C"},{"A","C"}};

private static Map<String, Integer> MAX_OF_EACH_ITEM = new HashMap<>();
static {
    MAX_OF_EACH_ITEM.put("A", 4);
    MAX_OF_EACH_ITEM.put("B", 2);
    MAX_OF_EACH_ITEM.put("C", 3);
}
```

This is the main method (which sets everything up for the start of the recursion):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BEST_WEIGHT_SO_FAR = 0;
    BEST_SOLUTION_SO_FAR = null;

    // start the recursion
    buildSolution(new boolean[POSSIBLE_SETS.length], new HashMap<>());

    // print solution
    System.out.println("BEST SOLUTION : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < POSSIBLE_SETS.length; i++) {
        if(BEST_SOLUTION_SO_FAR[i]){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(POSSIBLE_SETS[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the recursive method:

```
private static void buildSolution(boolean[] isSelected, Map<String, Integer> itemsUsed){
    boolean canBeExpanded = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
        // check whether another set can be added
        if(!isSelected[i]){

            // calculate new numbers of items used
            Map<String, Integer> itemsUsedB = new HashMap<>(itemsUsed);
            for (int j = 0; j < POSSIBLE_SETS[i].length; j++) {
                String key = POSSIBLE_SETS[i][j];
                if(itemsUsedB.containsKey(key))
                    itemsUsedB.put(key, itemsUsedB.get(key) + 1);
                else
                    itemsUsedB.put(key, 1);
            }

            // check whether this is possible
            boolean isPossible = true;
            for(String key : MAX_OF_EACH_ITEM.keySet()){
                if(itemsUsedB.containsKey(key) && itemsUsedB.get(key) > MAX_OF_EACH_ITEM.get(key)){
                    isPossible = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if not possible attempt next
            if(!isPossible)
                continue;

            // mark this solution as expandable
            canBeExpanded = true;

            // mark as selected
            isSelected[i] = true;

            // recurse
            buildSolution(isSelected, itemsUsedB);

            // undo mark
            isSelected[i] = false;
        }
    }
    // a solution that can no longer be expanded was found
    if(!canBeExpanded){
        int w = 0;
        int[] setSizeWeight = {0,5,15,20};
        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
            w += isSelected[i] ? setSizeWeight[POSSIBLE_SETS[i].length] : 0;
        }
        if(w > BEST_WEIGHT_SO_FAR){
            BEST_WEIGHT_SO_FAR = w;
            BEST_SOLUTION_SO_FAR = Arrays.copyOf(isSelected, isSelected.length);
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs:

> BEST SOLUTION
>   [A, B, C]
>   [A, C]
>   [A, B]
>   [A, C]

Which has a weight of 65.