# subgrouping of array items assignment problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could anyone guide me in tackling the below problem?

There are five different t-shirts which cost $8.

t-shirts
red - code 1
blue - code 2
green - code 3
black - code 4
yellow - code 5

conditions

1. if you buy 2 different t-shirts, you are eligible for a 5% discount on two t-shirts
2. if you buy 3 different t-shirts, you get a 10% discount.
3. if you buy 4 different t-shirts, you get a 20% discount.
4. if you buy all 5, you get a 25% discount.
5. if you buy 1 t-shirt, no discount

** if you buy 3 t-shirts, of which 2 are different, you get a 5% discount on the 2 that
form part of a set, but the 3rd t-shirt still costs $8.

** calculate the price giving as big a discount as possible.
example - how much does this t-shirts cart cost?

- red t-shirts  qty - 2
- blue t-shirts qty - 2
- green t-shirts qty - 2
- black t-shirt qty - 1
- yellow t-shirt qty - 1

total t-shirts in cart = 8

group 1 of these 8 t-shirts

- grouping of 5 items in cart - (red, blue, green, black, yellow) -> 25% discount = $30.0
- grouping of remaining 3 in cart - (red, blue, green) -> 10% Discount = $21.6

total = $51.6

a different way of grouping

- grouping of 4 items in cart - (red, blue, green, black) -> 20% discount = 25.60
- grouping of remaining 4 in cart - (red, blue, green, yellow) -> 20% Discount = $25.60

total = $51.2

need to offer $51.20 to customer

I am not sure how to create different groups however, I am able to create groups only one way and able to give discounts to customers. The below code is my first attempt and is not an optimal solution. Could anyone please guide me? I would help in the future.

```
const dis = (len) => {
  if (len === 5) return 0.25
  else if (len === 4) return 0.20
  else if (len === 3) return 0.10
  else if (len === 3) return 0.05
  else return 1;
}

const cart = (items) => {
    const dic = {};
    const arr = [];
    const total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (dic[items[i]]) {
          dic[items[i]] = dic[items[i]] + 1;
        } else {
          dic[items[i]] = 1;    
        }
    }
    
    const fn = function() {
        const lists = [];
        for (let key in dic) {
          if (dic[key] > 0) {
            lists.push(key)
            dic[key]--
          }
          if (dic[key] == 0) {
            delete dic[key]
          }
        }
        if (Object.keys(dic).length !== 0) {
          arr.push(fn())
        }
        return lists
      }
      
      arr.push(fn())
      
      for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].length === 1) {
                total += slen * 8
           } else {
                total += slen * 8 - (slen * 8 * dis(slen))
           }
      }
      return total;
    
}

// passing code
const cost = cart([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]);
console.log("cost: ", cost);
```

Comment: This sounds very similar to evaluating the better poker hand.

Comment: You might take a look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582504